# Analogue to vlib and vmap in Xilinx Vivado

Tags: xilinx, modelsim, vivado

I have a testing environment that I need to port to Xilinx Vivado.

What are the Vivado analogues to Modelsim vlib and vmap ? Please include entire command with any relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to `vlib` and `vmap` in Xilinx xSim.

It has these executables:

- `xvhdl` - like `vcom` - the VHDL compiler
- `xelab` - like `vopt` or `vsim -opt` - the elaboration tool
- `xsim` - like `vsim` - the simulator

`xvhdl` is not needed, you can call `xelab` with a file list and it will compile everything.

---

I'm not sure if it's worth porting a simulation environment to xSim, because it has many bugs and very poor VHDL-2008 support.